# The method managedQuery is undefined for the type Service_class Service_class.java

Tags: java, android, sqlite

What could be the cause of this? We are simply trying to query the browser history in the following service class however eclipse generates the error `The method managedQuery is undefined for the type Service_class  Service_class.java`

We have attempted to follow the eclipse suggestions - but it opened another can of worms entirely.

Example:

```
public class Service_class extends Service {
       String Dirty1 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty2 = "www.penthouse.com";
        String Dirty3 = "www.pornhub.com";
        String Dirty4 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty5 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty6 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty7 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty8 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty9 = "www.playboy.com";
        String Dirty10 = "www.playboy.com";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        String[] projection = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE,
                Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                        projection, null, null, null);
                String urls = "";
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                String url1 = null;
                String url2 = null;
                do {
                String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));

                if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty1)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty2)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty3)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty4)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty5)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty6)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty7)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty8)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty9)) {
                } else if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Dirty10)) {
                //if (url.toLowerCase().contains(Filthy)) {
                urls = urls
                + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE)) + " : "
                + url + "\n";
                Intent intent = new Intent(Service_class.this, Warning.class);
                Service_class.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
                } while (cursor.moveToNext()); 
            //  tv.setText(urls);


    }

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function managedQuery doesn't exist for Service.  It only exists for Activity.  You can still do queries, but you have to manage the cursor and close it by hand.

Comment: Since service doesn't have the query method either, you'll need to do it the hard way-  find the content provider you need, query it, and make sure to close the cursor when done.  Managing it is just like managing memory in C++-  when you're done with it you need to release the resources it uses (via close).  The managedQuery on Activity does it for you.  But for a service you have to do it all yourself.

Comment: Any tips on how this be accomplished? (We've never created a service class before - we just learned how)

Comment: What are you trying to query for?

Comment: Anything which matches our "Dirty" strings.

Comment: Try getContentResolver().query() in place of the managedQuery.

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreate method, line 3 you are using managed query method. Where is it defined?